# Selenium/Python doesn't recognize the function send_keys, it shows like plain text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

This is the code I'm running

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium_stealth import stealth
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains



options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

#Don't close the nav
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

# Chrome is controlled by automated test software
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
s = Service(r'C:\Users\santi\Downloads\a\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

# Selenium Stealth settings
stealth(driver,
      languages=["en-US", "en"],
      vendor="Google Inc.",
      platform="Win32",
      webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
      renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
      fix_hairline=True,
  )

driver.get("https://ikariam.es")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

#Email Fill In
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginRegisterTabs"]/ul/li[1]').click();
mailfinder = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div[2]/div/input').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
mailfinder = driver.send_keys('mail@outlook.com');
```

Note: I change the email for security measures.

> DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51575/devtools/browser/29423f16-f79c-4613-8156-4ed757ed937a
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\santi\OneDrive\Escritorio\ikabot2.py", line 43, in 
> mailfinder = driver.send_keys('mail@outlook.com');
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
> PS C:\Users\santi>

I don't know how to fix it. I did uninstall selenium and installed it back, it didn't work.

I'm trying to use the send_keys() function of webdriver on Chrome for filling up a form for automated login on this and other websites.

[enter image description here][1]

This is what appears over the send_keys() function
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Dar.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

This is true, but a WebElement does.

You are using driver.send_keys(), but you want to send the keys using the element that you specified when you used driver.find_element(). Instead of

```
mailfinder = driver.send_keys('mail@outlook.com');
```

simply do

```
mailfinder.send_keys('mail@outlook.com');
```